# MOSS 2007 and 2010 on the same server

Tags: 2007, installation

Looking to see if a MOSS 2007 and SharePoint 2010 farm(very small) can exist on the same same server.  We have a small infrastructure and I am looking to set up an environment as such.  2010 is installed as stand alone and MOSS 2007 will be installed as a farm install.  The OS build is 2008 R2 and running SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this will work to be honest, and if it did, you'd need a LOT of ram (> 16GB).

The binaries are installed on separate folders, sure, but you'd need to be double sure that ALL web applications, app pools and service accounts are kept completely separate, as well as SQL Database instances.

I can imagine you also having no end of headaches should go anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could run 2 virtual machines on the same box. One for SP2007 and one for SP2010.

Answer (score -1):

May be too late to answer here. But I just passed through same situation. 
Tricky part is to alter the registry settings. SharePoint setup goes and checks certain keys in order to verify the existence of other SharePoint version. If you alter them with trick it will never sense the other SharePoint version installation.

Here is detail post how you can do it
http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/installing-sharepoint-2010-and-moss-2007-on-single-machine/

Comment: It's never too late :-). However, while  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.